# How to disable column from vertical scrolling in html and bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to disable vertical scroll on one bootstrap column and make the other column scrollable. I've make this code :

HTML :

```
<div class="h-100">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 fixed h-100 bg-secondary"></div>
        <div
          class="col-9"
        >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum maxime aliquid sint natus ipsa molestiae quam blanditiis nisi ab laboriosam repellendus, corporis, modi omnis, veniam praesentium doloribus officia! In iusto quam delectus vero veniam. Quasi ex similique sint pariatur culpa labore, debitis quidem eveniet, sed praesentium consectetur nemo expedita</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS :

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

But the text on the second column goes inside the first column , how to fix that ?

Comment: To what element are you adding that CSS?

Comment: I've fixed the code, check it again

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Answer (score 0):

To disable the vertical scrolling of an element, apply the following CSS to the element:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Comment: The scrolling is already disabled, but the text on the right hand side goes inside the left column

Comment: That's because of your `position: fixed`, it takes the element out of the document flow; so other elements are not affected by it and the other columns takes it as if its not even there

Comment: Are the columns overlapping or do you mean the text is overflowing the column? Try overflow: none;

Comment: Ivan is correct, it sounds like your columns are actually overlapping each other. However, it doesn't actually seem like you need the position of the left column to be fixed.

Comment: `position: fixed` is not necessary; I don't think it does what OP think it does

Comment: @AymanTarig I don't think you need to use the .fixed class at all

Comment: @Xander tell me what should I do ? I want to achive this behavior in this site : https://blog.squarespace.com/blog/introducing-promotional-pop-ups

Comment: @AymanTarig Try making left column height 100% with overflow hidden. Then make sure right column has enough content inside it to be scrollable. The left column might not need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.side-panel {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 33%;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 33%;
  padding: 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 540px) {
  .main-container {
    display: block;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .side-panel {
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 250px;
    height: auto;
  }
  .content {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="side-panel"></div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
    magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
    deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: looks like you don't understand what i mean , see this site : https://blog.squarespace.com/blog/introducing-promotional-pop-ups

Comment: I want to achieve the same exact behavior

Comment: Then you should provide that in your question in the first place; that's not something you should be doing with Bootstrap columns; it will give you more troubles that creating it from scratch using flexbox

Comment: I try using flexbox but i get some responsiveness issues on small screen devices

Comment: I'll add an example

Comment: @AymanTarig check again

Comment: Thanks, it's working now